# R Shiny App for Linear Regression, Issue with Render Functions

Tags: r, output, shiny, render

When I run my code, I am not getting any errors and my app is staying live (not turning to a grey screen because of an error in code). However, I am not getting any output on the left side of my screen. I am assuming that I have some type of syntax error somewhere, but I can't quite figure it out. Here is my code, it should be easy to run on your own R Studio.

Here is my UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Linear Regression"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
    mainPanel(h2("Your Model"), dataTableOutput("table")),
    sidebarPanel(h2("Your Data"),

      fileInput("mydata", label = h4("Please upload the .xls, .txt, or.csv file you would like included in the analysis. Please use column names in your dataset.")),

      textInput("response", label=h4 ("What is the column name of your response variable?")),

      textInput("explan1", label=h4 ("What is the column name of your explanitory variable?")),

      actionButton("analysis", "Analyze!"),
      verbatimTextOutput("modelSummary"), 
      plotOutput("plot")

      )
    )
  )
)
```

And here is my Server:

```
shinyServer({
  function(input, output) ({
    observeEvent(input$analysis, {
     reactive({
        dat <- file.path(input$mydata)

        response=input$response
        explan1=input$explan1

        plot(input$response~input$explan1, data=dat)

        mean.response<-mean(dat$response,na.rm=T)

        abline(h=mean.Premium)

        model=lm(response~explan1, data = dat)

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
          plot(input$response~input$explan1, data= dat)
          abline(model,col="red")
        })

        output$modelSummary <- renderPrint({
          summary(model)
        })
      })   
    })
  })
})
```

For renderText I am trying to get it to output the whole summary.
Thanks!

Comment: Your app runs correctly as far as I can see. I can see all the menus on the left hand side of your app. If you mean that the problem occurs after you click 'Analyze' you should probably make a minimum reproducible example (i.e. one that does not require us creating a text file with variables to load in your app).

Answer (score 2):

You never assigned your `renderText`.  You also don't have the corresponding `textOutput` call in your `ui`.  Although you render an object in shiny it must be given as an output.  However, the `renderText` will not work for the `list` that is returned from `summary`.  I would use `renderPrint` and `verbatimTextOutput` to provide the output.

Also, I'm not sure about the `submitButton`.  I find much more control with the `actionButton` and an `observeEvent` block.  Personal preference but I can't seem to get `submitButton` to work properly for this so here is my solution.

Here is a minimally reproducible example demonstrating how to get the `summary` output printed in shiny using your layout.  Given that you didn't provide a reproducible data set I used the `mtcars` data.

```
library(shiny)
data(mtcars)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Linear Regression"),

      sidebarLayout(position = "right",
                    mainPanel(h2("Your Model"), dataTableOutput("table")),
                    sidebarPanel(h2("Your Data"),

                                 fileInput("mydata", label = h4("Please upload the .xls, .txt, or.csv file you would like included in the analysis.")),

                                 radioButtons("filetype", label = h4("Please select the type of data uploaded:"), c(".csv", ".txt", ".xls"), selected = ".xls"),

                                 textInput("response", label=h4 ("What is the column name of your response variable?")),

                                 textInput("explan1", label=h4 ("What is the column name of your explanitory variable?")),
                                 actionButton("analysis","Analyze!"),
                                 verbatimTextOutput("modelSummary")

                    )

      )),

    server = function(input, output) {
      observeEvent( input$analysis, {

          model=lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)


          output$modelSummary <- renderPrint({
            summary(model)
          })

      })
    }

))
```

Comment: I have edited my code above to show what I have now. I am still not getting an output in my app though there is no error or warning messages appearing in my console.

Comment: @LindseyRegister remove the `reactive` statement.  It's not necessary.

Comment: I removed it and got this error message when I tried to submit : Warning: Unhandled error in observer: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
observeEvent(input$analysis)

Comment: @LindseyRegister can you run my code without error?

Comment: @LindseyRegister what shiny version are you using?  My code runs without error with `shiny_0.12.2`.  If you copied my code exactly you should not receive that error.